# how to transform dfs

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search

I have Depth first searching algorithm whose pseudo code is given below:

```
   DFS(Vertex v)
    mark v visited
    make an empty Stack S
    push all vertices adjacent to v onto S
    while S is not empty do
        Vertex w is pop off S
        for all Vertex u adjacent to w do
            if u is not visited then
                mark u visited
                push u onto S
```

Now, I wish to convert the above dfs algorithm to breadth first search. I am implementing the program in C++. I am clueless how to go about the same.

EDIT: I know the pseudo code of bfs. What i am searching for is how to convert the above pseudo code of dfs to bfs.

Comment: Have you checked Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode

Comment: Read Cormen Leiserson Rivest - Introduction to algorithm to first understand what's the difference between DFS and BFS...

Comment: Change Stack to Queue and you're good

Comment: I don't understand your EDIT. If you know the pseudo code for BFS why are you asking how to convert the DFS to BFS?

Comment: There is a discrepancy in your code as to when a vertex is marked. Usually you mark a vertex *before* inserting it into the stack, but the neighbours of the initial vertex *v* are put into the stack without being marked visited. So they most likely will be visited twice. I guess you should put *v* itself into the stack. The problem is the same after you convert things to BFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BFS(Vertex v)
    mark v visited
    make an empty Queue Q
    Enqueue all vertices adjacent to v onto Q
    while Q is not empty do
        Vertex w is dequeued from Q
        for all Vertex u adjacent to w do
            if u is not visited then
                mark u visited
                enqueue u into Q
```

I hope this helps